# Render method from base class is called in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a search bar view:

```
App.Views.SearchField = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'keyup' : 'setFilter'
    },

    setFilter: function() {
        if (typeof this.filterCallback === 'function') {
            var filter = this.$el.val();
            this.filterCallback(filter);
        }
    },

    setFilterCallback: function(filterCallback) {
        this.filterCallback = filterCallback; //debounce here
    }
});
```

which is instanciated:

```
App.searchBar = new App.Views.SearchField({
    el: $('[data-role="top-search"]')
});
```

I connect to it from the initialize of another view:

```
App.Views.PartnerCompanies = App.Views.baseView.extend({

initialize: function( options )
{
    this.filter = '';
    App.searchBar.setFilterCallback(this.updateFilter);
    _.bindAll(this, "updateFilter");
}

render: function() {
console.log('rendering partnercompanies list');
// get data and show it.
}

updateFilter: function(filter) {
    console.log('filter updated');
    this.filter = filter;
    this.render();
},
```

But it doesn't work.

Output is:

```
rendering partnercompanies list 
filter updated [multiple times]
```

My `render()` method is never called after the filter is updated.

Checking in the debugger shows that the `render()` method of `Backbone.View` (the grandparent class) is being called. I am confused, as I used this same technique in another view and it works fine.

EDIT:

this in updateFilter refers to `App.searchBar`, not the `App.Views.PartnerCompanies` instance.

Comment: How are you instantiating your `App.Views.PartnerCompanies`? And if you `console.log(this)` in your `updateFilter()` method, what do you get? (You'll have to go spelunking in the resulting object to figure out what it is; Backbone objects don't get nice obvious names when logged to the console.)

Comment: added edit to the original question

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your edit, `this` in `updateFilter()` is an instance of `App.searchBar`, not `App.Views.PartnerCompanies`. As a result, when you call `this.render()` in `updateFilters`, it's called on the `App.searchBar` instance. `App.searchBar` doesn't have a `render()`, and nor does its parent `App.Views.SearchField`. But `App.Views.SearchField` inherits from `Backbone.View`, which does. *That's* why your method's calling the Backbone `render()` method.

---

So fundamentally, the problem is that `this` isn't referring to your `App.Views.PartnerCompanies`. This should be an easy fix. If you swap your `_.bindAll` and `setFilterCallback` lines in your `App.Views.PartnerCompanies`, you should be good to go. That way you're binding your `this` variable *before* assigning it as a callback, so the context won't change when it gets invoked in `updateFilter`.